# Textbox border disappears on click?

Tags: html, textbox, border, outline

so i have a basic html page setup with a download script. Everything seems to work fine aside from the textbox, when you click on the textbox to get ready to enter text, the border disappears, the text is still visible. Im not sure why this is happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I know this is a simple fix, so i am sorry for posting, however i couldn't find an answer anywhere.

The page is here: ~Snip~

Here is the textbox code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function SubmitFrm(){
        var Searchtxt = document.getElementById("txtSearch").value;
        window.location = "http://www.themodshop.co/database/download.php?f=" + Searchtxt + ".zip";
    }
</script>
<input name="txtSearch" maxlength="12" size="25" type="text" class="field" id="txtSearch" />
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have this line in style.css on line 66

```
 :focus {
/* outline:none; */
border: 0;
}
```

you can remove this.

Answer (score 3):

```
:focus {
    outline:none;
    border: 0;
}
```

In your style.css, line 66.

Please do not download code off of the internet without understanding it first. It's not good for you and it is dangerous for your users as one can easily inject malicious code into what you download.

Comment: Thank you so much, and i will definitely keep that in mind. Currently i try to download trusted and verified scripts. But you are most certainly right.